# Getting numeric output from predict() function instead of factors

Tags: r

I am running a decision tree to classify the quality of wines. When I run `predict()` it is outputting a numeric instead of the desired factor. I am using the code below:

```
library(rpart)

wine <- read.csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv", sep = ";")

wine$taste <- ifelse(wine$quality < 5, "yucky", "tasty")
wine$taste[wine$quality == 5] <- "fine"
wine$taste <- as.factor(wine$taste)

set.seed(123)

sample <- sample(nrow(wine), 0.7 * nrow(wine))
train <- wine[sample, ]
test <- wine[-sample, ]

DecisionTree <- rpart(taste ~ ., data = train)

pred <- predict(DecisionTree, test)
```

I am getting something that looks like this:

```
head(pred, 10)
   fine tastey yucky
6     1      0     0
14    1      0     0
18    1      0     0
23    1      0     0
24    1      0     0
25    0      1     0
26    1      0     0
30    0      1     0
33    1      0     0
35    1      0     0
```

I am trying to calculate the accuracy model using the formula:

```
acc <- table(pred, test$taste)
sum(diag(acc)) / sum(acc)
```

And I am getting the error the arguments are not the same length, which makes sense due to the format of the output of the pred. I think the output is supposed to look something like:

```
6     14     18     23     24     25     26     30     33 
  fine   fine   fine   fine   fine   fine   fine tasty   fine 
Levels: fine tasty yucky
```

I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. I suspect it has to do with the `rpart()` function. When I do the same process but with a random forest, it works perfectly. Any help would truly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify `type = "class"` in `predict`. From `?predict.rpart`:

> If type = "class":
>
> (for a classification tree) a factor of
>   classifications based on the responses.

You can confirm it gives your desired output:

```
pred <- predict(DecisionTree, test, type = "class") 

head(pred, 10)
#    3     7    12    14    15    21    22    23    27    30 
# fine  fine  fine  fine  fine tasty  fine  fine  fine tasty 
#Levels: fine tasty yucky
```

Comment: Wow that's so simple, thank you very much. I do have a follow-up if you have the time. My prediction is perfect. It makes me feel like something is wrong, do you have any idea why it would be doing that?

Comment: @AmeliaO'Leary It's because you are including `quality` as a predictor, which is what you defined `taste` in terms of

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much for everything.